# Multiple and fast external POST requests

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js server that making POST requests to an external API, each time I have to make ~10k requests (don't worry I'm not abusing the API) and I need that it will take around 2-3 minutes.

I'm using `request-promise` library in order to make the requests along with `Promise.all()` to wait for all the requests to resolve.
My problem is that the requests seems stuck and not running in parallel, I know that the promise executes as soon it's created but it seems that the `resolve` event can only listen to about 10 events at one time.

I tried updating the `maxListeners` and also using `es6-promise-pool` (with pool of 500) but no luck.

My next solution will probably be to use `child-process` with `fork`, will this solution seems the best for my problem?

Thanks!

code:

```
async function send_msg(msg) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            request.post(options, function (err, res, body) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error('error sending msg ' + err);
                    resolve(null);
                } else {
                    resolve(body);
                }
            })
        });
    }
}

async function send_msgs() {
    let msgs = await OutgoingMessage.findAll();
    for (let i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        promises.push(send_msg(msgs[i]).then(async (result) => {
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    let sid = result['MessageSid'];
                    let status = result['Status'];
                    msgs[i].update({sid: sid, status: status});
                } catch (e) {
                    logger.error(e + JSON.stringify(result));
                    msgs[i].update({status: 'failed'});
                }
            }
        }));

    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: what´s slow, node.js or the external api? identify the bottleneck and scale accordingly with some load balancing (nginx, pm2, ...). if a database is the problem, there are other ways to improve performance, depending on the database.

Comment: @luschn the bottleneck is node.js, the machine has 8 vCPUs with 16GB memory, the API can handle (already tested) this amount of requests.

Comment: can you add the snippet with the requests?

Comment: @PanosK added the code

Comment: are you using all those 8 vCPUs for sure? by default, node.js only uses 1.